# Bootstrap Column Sidebar Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have kind of an issue with the bootstrap grid system which confuses me, 
i have a 2 column layout that becomes a one column (col-xs-12) layout on mobile devices.

The issue i have is that on large screens, if my sidebar is higher than my "header div" it takes up whitespace.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 header">header</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sidebar">sidebar</div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 main_content">main_content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Heres a jsbin :
https://jsbin.com/helizemefa/edit?html,css,output

Maybe im just standing on the line right now..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header{
  background-color:red;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color:yellow;
  
}

.main_content {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 header">header</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right sidebar">sidebar</div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 main_content">main_content</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

you can add `pull-right` on your sidebar, like this

```
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sidebar pull-right">sidebar</div>
```